# Is it possible to change the desktop background with Java for different operating systems?

Tags: java

I have an idea for a class project which involves changing the desktop background image at different times.  I saw these questions:

[Can I change my Windows desktop wallpaper programmatically in Java/Groovy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750372/can-i-change-my-windows-desktop-wallpaper-programmatically-in-java-groovy)

[Programmatically change the desktop wallpaper periodically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12207574/programmatically-change-the-desktop-wallpaper-periodically)

[Change desktop background of MAC sytem using Java native access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199907/change-desktop-background-of-mac-sytem-using-java-native-access)

So I know it can be done on a specific operating system.  Is it possible to set it for different operating systems without writing separate programs?

Comment: You can check the OS and call the proper method for changing the background image based on the OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use:

```
String os = System.getProperty("os.name");
```

to determine what OS the app is running on, and decide what to do from there. Like so:

```
if (os.startsWith("Windows")) {
    // includes all Windows versions
} else if (os.startsWith("Mac")) {
    // includes all Mac OS versions
} else {
    // all others
}
```

I suggest looking up all of the different values `os.name` can have to be able to handle as many as possible. You might want to use enums for these values instead of checking `startsWith` like I did. [Here](http://www.java-tutorial.ch/java-server-faces/java-osname-system-property) is a list of values you might want to consider (although not very up to date).